# Hub not start in signal r

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am new Signal r.and i am trying to use it in mvc chat room application.
The issue is my hub not start for all user's. I have find alert only for one user.
And One more thing is . This is open in new Tab.

```
$(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

            chat.client.UserStatus = function (newUserId) {       
                alert('New User Comes');
            };


            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                 alert('Hub starts');
            });
        });
```

alert('Hub starts') comes only for admin user and for other user this alert not comes.

Comment: Any errors in the console for non-admin users?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a `.fail` to the deferred returned by `start`?

```
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
             alert('Hub starts');
        }).fail(function (e) {
             alert('There was an error');
             console.error(e);
        });
```

The `.done` function will only be called when `.start` is successful, so will be skipped when there is an error. Having a `.fail` function will give you a chance to handle any errors.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone arriving here in future, I found that `.fail` function suggested by [CodingWithSpike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28991478/629287) did not print anything to the console.

I added the following before the call to `.start()`:

```
$.connection.hub.error(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

(In my case, it printed `You are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version 1.5, server version 1.4.` because I was using CDNs to load the latest jQuery and SignalR, and these weren't compatible with the SignalR libraries I'd added to my solution.)